# Passing an additional argument in inherited class

Tags: python-2.7, class, pyqt, parameter-passing, signature

I have an inherited class where I try to use an additional argument (`language`). I'm not sure where I have to place this argument within `__init__`.

Calling the class:

```
self.highlighter = Highlighter(self.editor.document(), language='yaml')
```

Class:

```
class Highlighter(QSyntaxHighlighter):

    def __init__(self, language, parent=None):
        self.language = language

        super(Highlighter, self).__init__(parent)

        if self.language == 'yaml':
            self.lguge_ymal()
```

Currently, I get an error when I run the code, no matter where I place the `language` argument:

```
TypeError: __init__() got multiple values for keyword argument 'language'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the moment, the signature of your `__init__` has one positional argument (`language`) and one keyword argument (`parent`). But you then call it by passing the parent as a postional argument and the language as a keyword argument. So you end up effectively passing the language value *twice* (hence the error).

I think it would make more sense to define your class like this:

```
class Highlighter(QSyntaxHighlighter):
    def __init__(self, parent=None, language=''):    
        super(Highlighter, self).__init__(parent)
        self.language = language
        if self.language == 'yaml':
            self.lguge_ymal()
```

Which you can then use in any of these ways:

```
self.highlighter = Highlighter(self.editor.document(), language='yaml')
self.highlighter = Highlighter(self.editor.document(), 'yaml')
self.highlighter = Highlighter(self.editor.document())
self.highlighter = Highlighter(language='yaml')
```